# this. and List<T>

Tags: c#, list, this

I am having trouble understanding how to initialize a List of objects and use it with methods inside of a class.  I understand the mechanics of the List, but not how to initialize it inside a method and use it later.

For example, I want to have a class that creates the List when it is constructed.  Then, I want to use a method of that class to add elements to the list.  The elements in the list are objects defined by the SolidWorks API.

So, to construct the List, I used:

```
public class ExportPoints : Exporter
{
    public List<SldWorks.SketchPoint> listOfSketchPoints;

    public ExportPoints(SldWorks.SldWorks swApp, string nameSuffix) :
        base(swApp, nameSuffix)
    {
        List<SldWorks.SketchPoint> listOfSketchPoints  = new List<SldWorks.SketchPoint>();
    }

    public void createListOfFreePoints()
    {
        try
        {
            //imagine more code here
            this.listOfSketchPoints.Add(pointTest);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Print(e.ToString());
            return;
        }
    }
```

This fails during execution as if the **listOfSketchPoints** was never initialized as a **List**.

So, I tried a *hack* and this worked:

```
public ExportPoints(SldWorks.SldWorks swApp, string nameSuffix) :
    base(swApp, nameSuffix)
{
    List<SldWorks.SketchPoint> listOfSketchPoints = new List<SldWorks.SketchPoint>();
    this.listOfSketchPoints = listOfSketchPoints;
}
```

This approach creates the behavior that I want.  However, it seems that I lack some understanding as to why this is necessary.

- Shouldn't it be possible to "initialize" a List that is a property of your object with a constructor?
- Why would you need to create the list, then assign the pointer of that new List to your property?

Comment: That's not a hack that's the way programming languages work. You're first constructor was recreating a local version of the lisOfSketchPoints; all you needed to do was - this.listOfSketchPoints = new List<SldWorks.SketchPoint>(); in your constructor. Oh, and I suggest making the listOfSketchPoints private.

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize the list, best in the constructor. But you are creating a local list there. So replace

```
List<SldWorks.SketchPoint> listOfSketchPoints  = new List<SldWorks.SketchPoint>();
```

with

```
this.listOfSketchPoints = new List<SldWorks.SketchPoint>();
```

I'm fairly sure that you now know why you should name your variables carefully ;-)

Comment: Maybe you should explicitly mention that the local variable is eclipsing the member variable because it has the same name.

Comment: @TimothyShields: i've added a note, however, i think that he thought that he had to use the same name to initialize the field/property, but actually he created a new local list accidentially.

Comment: This captures exactly the misunderstanding...  I was "creating" a new this.list inside my constructor when I should have just assigned the "pointer" as this.list = new List<>;  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your constructor, in the first example, you are creating a second local variable named `listOfSketchPoints` and assigning that to the new list.  It is on the stack and destroyed as soon as you exit the constructor.

By assigning it to `this`, you are keeping the reference alive and allowing the object to be used later.  You could achieve the same effect with this:

```
public ExportPoints(SldWorks.SldWorks swApp, string nameSuffix) :
    base(swApp, nameSuffix)
{
    this.listOfSketchPoints  = new List<SldWorks.SketchPoint>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you specify a type next to an identifier in your constructor like this:

```
public ExportPoints(SldWorks.SldWorks swApp, string nameSuffix) :
    base(swApp, nameSuffix)
{
    List<SldWorks.SketchPoint> listOfSketchPoints  = ...
}
```

You're declaring a new variable that is totally unrelated to the field you declared above. You initialize a new instance of `List<T>` and assign it to the local variable, but you didn't do anything with the field. This is why you get an error that the field has not been assigned a value.

To initialize the field, you can simply assign it directly like this:

```
public ExportPoints(SldWorks.SldWorks swApp, string nameSuffix) :
    base(swApp, nameSuffix)
{
    this.listOfSketchPoints = new List<SldWorks.SketchPoint>();
}
```

Also note, in the absence of local variables or parameters of the same name, using `this.` to refer to class members is optional (but still generally preferred to avoid confusion).

Answer (score 1):

Change your constructor to be:

```
this.listOfSketchPoints = new List<SldWorks.SketchPoint>()
```

Otherwise the listOfSketchPoints in the constructor is only in scope of the constructor and the class property will never be initialised.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ExportPoints(SldWorks.SldWorks swApp, string nameSuffix) :
    base(swApp, nameSuffix)
{
    this.listOfSketchPoints  = new List<SldWorks.SketchPoint>();
}
```

or

```
public List<SldWorks.SketchPoint> listOfSketchPoints = new List<SldWorks.SketchPoint>();

public ExportPoints(SldWorks.SldWorks swApp, string nameSuffix) :
    base(swApp, nameSuffix)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably cjeck out this code .It would be better while defining objects globally for a particualr class it should be declared using a private keyword rather than a public keyword.Since another form or class may try to access the value of the variable defined for the particular class or program. (it becomes a security risk) .As the object is declared globally it can be used in any methods within the same class.Kindly check this code

```
public class ExportPoints : Exporter

{
private List<SldWorks.SketchPoint> listOfSketchPoints;

public ExportPoints(SldWorks.SldWorks swApp) :
    base(swApp)
{
     listOfSketchPoints  = new List<SldWorks.SketchPoint>();
}

public void createListOfFreePoints(string pointTest)
{
    try
    {
        //imagine more code here
        listOfSketchPoints.Add(pointTest);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Print(e.ToString());
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: you're right of course.  I made it public just because I wanted to focus on the issue of the creation of the List<>.  Thanks!